# How do I get questions regarding emails to get more attention?

Tags: discussion

This may be a non-question or a question in the wrong place, so I understand if its rapidly shut down, but I notice that any questions I've asked about email get little attention and very rarely answered. I did a quick search and that seems to be a broader phenomenon on the `imap` and `email` tags.

Is this just not an area not of interest to SO users, or is it something to do with the way the questions are being posed. Thanks

Comment: [Where are your questions tagged `email`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1675004+%5Bemail%5D)?

Comment: hi @bfavaretto `http://superuser.com/questions/590227/dummies-guide-to-mailutils` would be a question tagged `email` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578942/rpython-and-imaplib-sending-a-search-query-to-imap` would be an example of one tagged `imap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's just strictly a matter of user interest and the amount of beginners entering the area. The most common and frequented tags are definitely the languages themselves, c#, java, php, which both have a lot of interest and have frequent questions from people with little experience. This leads to a lot of activity.

Email is probably not the favorite area for most people, and anyone getting into it is probably not a beginning programmer, so it's unlikely to be heavily trafficked.

I honestly think it happens to many tags.  For example, I'm personally a fan of Hadoop, which gets even less traffic than email. I'm pretty confident its for the reasons I described: it's very specialized, and most people entering are already fairly experienced programmers, though often they need lots of setup advice ;) .

Comment: Thanks @greedybuddha .. kinda says it all. :-)